# term by term antidifferentiation (Abbott exercise 6.5.4)

Tags: real-analysis

[image]
Can someone check my proof:
**6.5.4.** (a) Let $x \in (-R, R)$ be arbitrary.  Since $f(x)$ converges at $x$, by theorem 6.5.2, $f(x)$ converges uniformly on $[-|x|, |x|]$. We also have $F(0) = 0$. Thus by the term by term differentiation theorem, $F(x)$ converges uniformly on $[-|x|, |x|]$ and is differentiable term by term on $[-|x|, |x|]$. In particular, $F(x)$ converges at $x$ and $F'(x) = f(x)$. Since $x$ was arbitrary, this holds for each $x \in (-R, R)$.

(b) Since $g'(x) = F'(x)$, $g(x) = F(x) + C$ for some $C \in \mathbb{R}$. Since $F(0) = 0$, it follows that $C = g(0)$. Thus $g(x) = g(0) + F(x) = g(0) + \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\frac{a_n}{n + 1}x^{n + 1}$.

Comment: What on earth is theorem 6.5.2? What book is this?

Comment: If a power series converges pointwise on the set $A \subseteq R$, then it converges uniformly on any compact set $K \subseteq A$. This is the generalization that was proved in the book (theorem 6.5.5).

Comment: I would actually if you just gave me the name of the book as I requested.

Comment: @IAmNoOne Oh sorry I put it in the title. Here is the link: https://elliespathtostatistics.files.wordpress.com/2018/03/abbott-second-edition.pdf